# How does sqlite cache_spill pragma exactly work?

Tags: sqlite

I would like to know how the `cache_spill = false` pragma exactly works. I understand that once the cache is full it should be written to disk even before a commit actually happens. I understand this could be problematic because it requires keeping an exclusive lock since that moment until the actual commit takes place. I understand one could increment the cache size to ameliorate this potential problem. And I understand that one would like to magically avoid any spill under such circumstances although I don't believe the cache_spill pragma works in magical ways. So:

1. Does it make further API calls that require cache growing to fail, so signaling the user a commit is in order?
2. Does it stop writing to the memory cache and use the disk instead, losing performance but avoiding the spill?

Answer (score 1):

The cache spilling affected by this pragma happens only when the database runs into a soft memory limit.

If you inhibit these spills, the changed data is just kept in memory.
This might result in an out-of-memory error if you need some memory for more changed data (or for anything else).
In practice, most operating systems will just swap out some data to disk (which is more inefficient because the data must be read back from swap before it is actually committed).